# Laravel update query use

Tags: laravel

I used this query to update the status column.

```
$val="1";
vehicles::where('id' , '=' , $veh_status)->update(['status' => $val]);
```

But when I submitted the status value doesn't change.

Comment: `$veh_status` does not seem to be an ID.

Comment: Check if `status` is listed as `$fillable` in `Vehicles` model. It's a common mistake when utilizing mass assignment feature in Eloquent.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the problem is there because you haven't given much info to work with, but you can check these suggestions:

- Check if the column is set to be mass assignable in the model class, that is, it is in the fillable[] array.
- make sure the id you pass to the `where()` function is valid.
- Try using another function, `save()` which will achieve the same results you seek, like this;

  `// filter the vehicle 
  $vehicle = vehicles::where('id', '=', $veh_id)->first();
   or
  $vehicle = vehicles::find($veh_id); 
  $vehicle->status = 1;
  $vehicle->save();`

Lastly, I noticed your id variable you pass to the where the () function is called `$veh_status` "presumably - vehicle status" and not `$veh_id`, "presumably - vehicle id" so probably check that out.

Ref: [Laravel Model Update documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#updates)

Comment: The id passed in where function is ok. problem is in database the status value doesnt change

Comment: Did you try my suggestions? What happened? What else did you try...you must try to give as much information about your problem to get help.

Answer (score 1):

you can trace your query by using `->toSql()` method !
try this to find whats happening in back